How to use DT layout option in R?
I want to have the paging displayed at the bottom left side of the table and found that in JS, the DT layout option seems to do exactly that. However, I haven't found a way to use in R nor someone asking about it.
Here is the desired output (edited with GIMP) :

Here is my attempt at reproducing it with the layout option :
library(DT)

datatable(
  iris, 
  options = list(
    layout = list(
      topStart = "pageLength",
      bottomStart = "info",
      bottom2Start = "paging"
    )
  )
)


As written in your linked documentation, layout is available since DataTables 2.0.0, however, DT currently uses DataTables 1.x, so this most probably can't work.

Use the older dom option instead. There are many "pure" DataTables (i.e. HTML/JavaScript) examples in Stack Overflow, and I expect there are some R/DT/Shiny examples also.

Using the dom option as mentioned, options = list(dom = 'ltipr') would get you nearly there, but to left align the paging I think you would need to use some CSS.

Oh so that's why it doesn't work, thank you for pointing it out. I've seen some questions on OS using CSS to align DT elements so I'll be looking into them.

As Jan pointed out, the layout option is not yet available for the R DT package. In the meantime, I managed to get the layout I was looking for with the following CSS code.
If you wish to use it for elements other than the info and paging, don't forget to inspect the webpage of you shiny app to get its exact class.
Here is the Shiny App with CSS styling :
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)



ui <- basicPage(
  DTOutput("dummyTable", fill = TRUE),
  
  tags$style(
    HTML(".dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
          float: left}
          .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info {
          float: right}")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dummyTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, options = list(dom = "l<t>ipr"))
  })
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {stopApp()})
}


shinyApp(ui, server)

